# Retrieving multiple tables using a stored procedure in C#.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How can I create a stored procedure that can SELECT FROM several tables and display the result in a HTML table? I did that by using only one table and used in ASP.NET using C#.

I used grid view, but it successed with only one table. I could have used a stored procedure that use only one table. I also used DataSource, but it worked with only one table.

Answer (score 3):

That would be something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc 
as
BEGIN

  SELECT a.columna, b.columnb, c.columnc 
  from table a join table b on a.id=b.id
  join table c on c.id=a.id

END
```

Now your markup:

```
<asp:gridview id="grid" runat="server" DataSource="SqlDataSource1" .../>

<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" SelectCommand="MyProc" 
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString%>"
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can return multiple tables from a stored procedure. One for each `SELECT` statement, then you fill a dataSet from the dataAdapter. Each `SELECT` statement's data will be in a seperate table within the dataSet.

I hope thats what you meant!